# Shelosha Vetish'im Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred ninety-three?

### ?שלושה ותשעים ומאתים - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 293.

For the first time since I started checking, I think, I'm unable to come up with a lazy gematria for this one. This is not a pun.

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous two hundred ninety-two entries in this ongoing series.

Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 14 possible Jewish calendar combinations. In a year where one of the following 4 combinations happen  - בש"ה הכ"ז הש"א זח"א - there are **293** days that are not Shabbos or Yom Tov (Chutz L'Aretz) and you may do Melacha.

An explanation of what בש"ה הכ"ז הש"א זח"א mean.

- The first letter is the day of the week that Rosh HaShana comes out on.
- The second letter tells you whether Cheshvon and Kisleiv have both 29 days = (ח) for Chasair. If Cheshvon has 29 days and Kisleiv has 30 days then = (כ) for K'Sidran. If both Chesvan and Kisleiv have 30 days then = (ש) for Shlaima.
- The third letter is the day of the week that Pesach comes out on.

Comment: Usually ש is used for the middle letter in the third case, not מ (it stands for שלימה). So the first and third kevios would usually be expressed as בש"ה and הש"א, respectively.